# Make changes in /includes/http.php update safe

Tags: include

I've commented out the following two lines in the http.php,

```
function send_origin_headers() {
    $origin = get_http_origin();

    if ( is_allowed_http_origin( $origin ) ) {
    //  @header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' .  $origin );
        //@header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
        if ( 'OPTIONS' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] )
            exit;
        return $origin;
    }

    if ( 'OPTIONS' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
        status_header( 403 );
        exit;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Since the header is otherwise sent twice and it comes to problems. Now I want to install this change update safe in my WordPress installation. How can I do that?

Comment: Find out _why_ the header is sent twice, and fix that instead of editing core files.

Answer (score 0):

Fuxia is right, you need to fix the underlying problem; however I can't resist answering with a quick and dirty solution; and its also useful when customizing plugins.

*(you may also be able to protect the file by changing its owner and permissions - but I don't know all the implications)*

1. immediately after the starting comments in **your** *http.php* add this line:
   `$GLOBALS['IS_MY_HTTP_SCRIPT'] = TRUE;`
2. make a back-up of your modified script and place in a directory that is update safe
3. create and activate the following plugin, or add its code to some existing script.

   ```
   <?php
   /*
   Plugin Name: replace update with my backup
   */
   if (empty($GLOBALS['IS_MY_HTTP_SCRIPT']) && ! get_transient('myRollbackFailure') ) {
     if (copy( '/some_update_safe_dir/myhttp.bkup', '/path_to/wp-includes/http.php') ) {
       $msg = 'Updated script replaced by my copy - I may need to modify my version';
     } else {
       $msg = 'script updated - unable to replace with my version';
      // prevent repeated failed attempts for 1 hour
      set_transient( 'myRollbackFailure', 'fail', 60 * 60 );
     }
     // maybe some code to email msg to admin
   }
   ```

Your version of the script will replace the updated version on first subsequent site navigation or visit.

I've tested it and it works on Apache; I don't know whether on Windows its different file locking during "execution" will prevent the reversion.